# How to get total sum of a column in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the sum of a column in My ng-repeat table. I shared the image of the table below this paragraph.

[image]

Code of the table is given below.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Ref No</th><th>Model</th><th>IMEI</th><th>Color</th><th>Warranty</th><th>Branch</th><th>Party</th><th>Date of Sell</th><th>Amount</th>
   </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in Approve"><td> {{ x.sno }} </td><td> {{ x.p_model }} </td><td> {{ x.imei }} </td><td> {{ x.color }} </td><td> {{ x.warrenty }} </td><td> {{ x.branch }} </td><td> {{ x.party }} </td><td> {{ x.dsell }} </td><td ng-init="Approve.total.amount = Approve.total.amount + x.rate"> {{ x.amount | number:2 }} </td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="color:red;">Grand Total</td><td>{{ grandtotal }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

My Controller code given below.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("api/sold_out.php").then(function (response) {
$scope.Approve = response.data.message;
});
});
</script>
```

Jsone fetch from the server:

```
{"message":[{"0":"2","sno":"2","1":"Huawei P9 Lite ","p_model":"Huawei P9 Lite ","2":"545454545454","imei":"545454545454","3":"White","color":"White","4":"CGC","warrenty":"CGC","5":"50","amount":"50","6":"1","sell":"1","7":"27\/02\/2017","dsell":"27\/02\/2017","8":"1","transfer":"1","9":"MANSOURA","branch":"MANSOURA","10":"Cloud International Co Will","party":"Cloud International Co Will"},{"0":"3","sno":"3","1":"Samsung Galaxy J7 6","p_model":"Samsung Galaxy J7 6","2":"456545454545545","imei":"456545454545545","3":"Gold","color":"Gold","4":"Gasham","warrenty":"Gasham","5":"100","amount":"100","6":"1","sell":"1","7":"27\/02\/2017","dsell":"27\/02\/2017","8":"1","transfer":"1","9":"MANSOURA","branch":"MANSOURA","10":"Cloud International Co Will","party":"Cloud International Co Will"}]}
```

I need to display the total **sum** value of the **Amount** column in the Grand Total area.

Comment: How about you create a function in your controller that will sum those values from your list, and reference that function in the html?

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking, but having this sort of computation logic inside your view is not a best practice. I suggest push this field into the model, or calculate that in your controller and then push into the model. It will also allow you to write unit tests on how this is calculated.

Comment: Let me know the steps.

Comment: Following what @seva said, you could also implement a filter in order to display your grand total such as `<td style="color:red;">Grand Total</td><td>{{ Approve | sumColumn: 'amount' }}</td>`. If you're interested in this, I'll write it as an answer with an example

Comment: Can you show Me a full example with My code? I updated the code like you said. Created a filter, but it made the whole thing diss-appeared.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TAFqy/92/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, one way to solve this could be by using a custom filter that would look like :

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('Test', [])
    .filter('sumByColumn', function () {
      return function (collection, column) {
        var total = 0;

        collection.forEach(function (item) {
          total += parseInt(item[column]);
        });

        return total;
      };
    });
})();
```

You could then call that filter on your collection by specifying which column you want to sum:

```
<td>{{ Approve | sumByColumn: 'amount' }}</td>
```

The advantage of using a filter here, IMHO, is that it is reusable. Whenever you need to sum a specific column on any data, you can do it using this filter again.

Of course I advise you to improve it by checking that the column value is a number for example...etc...Since it is a filter, you can easily write tests for it.

I've created a JsFiddle in order to demonstrate how it works within your context https://jsfiddle.net/7b3q2q5p/4/

Comment: I added the controller code to the question. Can you update the controller code with the filter? I added the filter code, but not showing the total value.

Comment: Well, since I do not have access to your context (a.k.a your server response), I cannot really paste your controller and make it work. I think this is **not working** because of **the way you grab the data from the server** (that could be one explanation). I think here you should use some dependency injection in order to avoid putting this kind of logic within your controller. If you're using a `Router`, I advise you to use it's `resolve` method and inject the server response from here. Not only it will make it more testable, but it will also make it less prone to error.

Comment: After using the filter, I got result like this `05001000` both 500 and 1000 converted to a string and come together.

Comment: I updated the code with the json result. Where code fetch the result.

Comment: Then use a `parseInt` in order to convert your string value into integer. I updated my jsFiddle and my example

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Ref No</th><th>Model</th><th>IMEI</th><th>Color</th><th>Warranty</th><th>Branch</th><th>Party</th><th>Date of Sell</th><th>Amount</th>
   </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in Approve"><td> {{ x.sno }} </td><td> {{ x.p_model }} </td><td> {{ x.imei }} </td><td> {{ x.color }} </td><td> {{ x.warrenty }} </td><td> {{ x.branch }} </td><td> {{ x.party }} </td><td> {{ x.dsell }} </td><td ng-init="$parent.grandtotal  = grandtotal + x.rate"> {{ x.amount | number:2 }} </td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="color:red;">Grand Total</td><td>{{ grandtotal }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.